# Sql da busca padrão por string do phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql

Preciso obter o mesmo resultado de uma busca em uma tabela que me retorne a mesma porção de string e que desconsiderasse a acentuação gráfica da busca.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: voce quer fazer isso no phpmyadmin ou num php?

Comment: se for por php voce primeiro deve remover os acentos de uma $string. depois deve calcular o length dessa string.. use o strlen() do php.

Comment: Vou fazer isso com php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, uma solução possível é você executar uma SQL para buscar os dados que você deseja, para isso vá até a aba SQL do phpmyadmin e execute a seguinte query:

```
SELECT * from nome_da_tabela WHERE content like '%texto_vai_aqui_%';
```

Substitua os campos:

"nome_da_tabela": pelo nome da tabela de onde os dados que você quer buscar estão;
"texto_vai_aqui": texto que deseja procurar;

Para acentuação redifina o collation para utf8 caso seja o caso.

```
SET NAMES 'utf8';
```

[Documentação - Character Sets, Collations, Unicode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset.html)